# Get parts of URL after domain name //... by splitting URL into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have make this code:

```
var newURL = $(".list-portfolio a").attr("href"),
    pathArray = newURL.split( '/' ),
    secondLevelLocation = pathArray[0];
console.log(pathArray);

    var pathArray = pathArray[3, 4];
```

The pathArray value is `["http:", "", "www.mikevierwind.nl", "portfolio", "ruimzicht.html"]`

How can i get the last 2 items of this array. I want that the results is portfolio/ruimzicht.html.

Comment: `var last2 = pathArray[3]+'/'+pathArray[4]` this could be...if you have fixed url

Comment: var pathArrayNew = pathArray[3]+"\/"+pathArray[4]; ?

Comment: You could do `.prop("pathname")` on the element.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You don't need any of this, you just want `window.location.pathname`:

```
> window.location.pathname
"/questions/11898626/get-items-of-the-array/11898963"
```

This will let you in the future have directories like "portfolio/2012/ruimzicht.html", and change domains to say "www.mikevierwind.???" without changing your code.

---

If you are not currently on the domain (and can't do the above), you can do it your way with a one-liner:

```
> pathArray.slice(-2).join('/')
"portfolio/ruimzicht.html"
```

But this is not future-proof like the above. To make it future-proof, you can do:

```
> url.split(document.domain)[1].slice(1)
"portfolio/2012/ruimzicht.html"
```

One would do this generally on foreign URLs when you are not currently on the domain and thus can't do `window.location.pathname`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use array length if you don't have a fixed size or number of elements.

```
var path = array[array.length-2]+'/'+array[array.length-1];
```

If you just want the path use plain JS or jQuery as they suggest you in comments.

```
//Plain JS
var path = window.location.pathname;
//jQuery
$(location).attr('pathname');
```

Comment: What I meant was accessing that property on the `a` element.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
console.log(new URL(document.URL));
```

you would get object of URL

Answer (score 1):

```
location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf(location.host)+location.host.length)
```

try this!
it's contains URL parameters

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
var newURL = $(".list-portfolio a").attr("href"),
    pathArray = newURL.split( '/' ),
    secondLevelLocation = pathArray[0];
console.log(pathArray);

var pathArray = pathArray[3] +'/'+ pathArray[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or May be something like this

```
var newURL = $(".list-portfolio a").attr("href"),
pathArray = newURL.split( '/' ),
secondLevelLocation = pathArray.shift();

var pathArray = pathArray.join('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short

Ninjagecko gives excelent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11898963/860099) - I improve it a little: you don't need use `window` prefix, just

```
location.pathname
```

And some alternative way to get two last array items by use `at()`

```
[ pathArray.at(-2), pathArray.at(-1) ]
```

```js
pathArray = ["http:", "", "www.mikevierwind.nl", "portfolio", "ruimzicht.html"];

result = [ pathArray.at(-2), pathArray.at(-1) ]

console.log(result.join`/`);
```